# d3 nested selection tutorial not rendering table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following the nested selections tutorial here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/.

I've copied the code, but it is failing to bind the values to the `td`s.  The table structure is being created, but the values aren't being entered in to the `td` elements. If I log `d` on the `td` append functions, it prints the arrays from `matrix`.  Even if I put in `return 1`, the `td`s aren't populated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

</style>

<body>


</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var matrix = [
  [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
  [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15],
];

var body = d3.select("body");

var table = body.append("table");

var tr = table.selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix)
  .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) { 
        console.log(d);
        return d; 
    })
  .enter().append("td");

</script>
```

Console output:

```
Array [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] nested_selections.html:30:6
Array [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ] nested_selections.html:30:6
Array [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] nested_selections.html:30:6
Array [ 12, 13, 14, 15 ] nested_selections.html:30:6
```

If I try grabbing the index like this:

```
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d, i) { 
        console.log(d[i]);
        return d; 
    })
  .enter().append("td");
```

I get this console output (which looks like it combines index of array and nested array):

```
0 nested_selections.html:30:6
5 nested_selections.html:30:6
10 nested_selections.html:30:6
15 nested_selections.html:30:6
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the content of the `<td>`s is never set. You need to add something like `append('td').text(_.identity)`*, for just setting their contents to `d`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qosgvbhh/)

Or `.html()` is available for hypertext contents.

**: `_` is `underscore` or `lodash`*

Comment: Thank you, I see some of the previous examples simply calling .text when needed like this case.